# How Can i write Junit for Spring validator used with DataBinder

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, spring-validator

```
public class ValidatorUtil {

  @Autowired
  Validator validator;

  public <T> void validateAndThrowException(T obj) {
    DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(obj);
    binder.setValidator(validator);
    binder.validate();
    BindingResult results = binder.getBindingResult();
    if (results.hasErrors() && null != results.getAllErrors()) {
    // DO something
    }
  }
```

I am unable to execute Junit for this.

My Junit configuration is :

```
  @Spy
  @InjectMocks
  ValidatorUtil validatorUtil;

  @Spy
  Validator validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
```

Here As DataBinder's object is created using new keyword. then `binder.setValidator(validator)` throws illegalArgumentException. How can I wrote Junit for same ?

Note: I am using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Comment: Could you provide the full stacktrace? The complete test fixture will be helpful as well.
Meanwhile, does `ValidationUtil` refers to `ValidatorUtil`? Or are these totataly separate classes?

Comment: Thanks for correcting ValidationUtil and ValidatorUtil.

Comment: Could you add the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` class source code along with the full exception stacktrace?